# Working Capital Change vs. Working Capital Changes-Total

Tags: capital-structure

I am working with compustat data and I can't figure out difference between 2 columns:

Working Capital Changes - Total

Working Capital Change / Other / Increase/(Decrease)

For the same date columns have significantly different numbers